# Recommend a mail server setup for multiple domains

Tags: email, debian, domain, email-server, mx-record

I've just set up a new Debian web server which I have done plenty of times before, but I want to add a mail server which I have never done before.

I am aware of [this question](http://www.serverfault.com/questions/1152/recommended-personal-mail-server-setup), but I would like someone to recommend packages and briefly explain how to use them for **providing pop/imap access on multiple domains**, a concept that has confused me for a while.

I'm planning for this server to grow slowly but surely, from serving an initial 5 or 6 domains to about 20 in the first year, continuing at this rate. (yes, I've jumped on the cloud bandwaggon).

At the moment, I have a DNS-A record pointing to my server's IP and nothing else. I'm assuming that I need a DNS-MX record pointing there too, but I haven't read up about it yet so today that's what I'll be doing. Hopefully reading up on the subject and the help that I get here will get my server up and running in no time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny**

It's a well-documented solution, which is extendable. Discussion about it on the [mailing list](http://workaround.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/workaround-chitchat) and directly on the howto pages.

Comment: Great tutorial. It does go very deep for newbies, but if you stick at it, it gets everything covered!

Comment: Right, my mailserver setup is based on that howto since Debian Woody. Just in case, look at my howtos (http://lugh.ch/howtos/) some of them are based around this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend virtual mailboxes on postfix with setup described here: http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/virtual2.html